# jquery .done() still runs before deferred.resolve()

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I have read several questions here on this topic and I still can't see what is wrong. I have two functions, one initializes an image from a file and reads its dimensions, setting them to object's variables. The second one checks if the dimensions are within limits.

The functions:

```
  checkDimensions: function() {
      console.log('entering chekDimensions');
      if (options.maxDimensionsWH > 0) {

        console.log(this.checkWidth);
        console.log(this.checkHeight);
        if ((this.checkWidth <= options.maxDimensionsWH || this.checkHeight <= options.maxDimensionsWH)
             && (this.checkWidth > 0 && this.checkHeight > 0)) {
            console.log('returning true');
            return true;    
        } else {
            console.log('returning false');
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        return true;
    }
  },
  initializeCheckImage: function(file) {
    console.log('entering initialization');
    var d = $.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        var img = new Image;
        img.onload = function() {
          this.checkWidth = img.width;
          this.checkHeight = img.height;
          console.log('initializing the image');
          console.log(this.checkWidth);
          console.log(this.checkHeight);
          d.resolve();
        };
        console.log('assigning reader.result');
        img.src = reader.result;
      };
      console.log('assigning a file to the reader');
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      console.log('returning deferred');
      return d.promise();
  }
```

And how they are called:

```
this.initializeCheckImage(file).done(check = this.checkDimensions());
```

From the console, it is clearly visible, that execution of the second function occurs before the `d.resolve();` is called.

```
> 21:13:34.460 entering initialization
> 21:13:34.461 assigning a file to the reader
> 21:13:34.462 returning deferred
> 21:13:34.462 entering chekDimensions
> 21:13:34.462 0
> 21:13:34.463 0
> 21:13:34.463 chekDimensions returning false
> 21:13:34.478 assigning reader.result
> 21:13:34.493 initializing the image
> 21:13:34.494 30
> 21:13:34.494 30
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: `.done(check = this.checkDimensions());` You're invoking `checkDimensions` immediately, assigning its return value to `check`, and passing that return value to `done` as the Promise callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise function is being immediatly invoked:

```
this.initializeCheckImage(file).done(check = this.checkDimensions());
```

The `done` function should accept as a parameter an `executer`:

> A function that is passed with the arguments resolve and reject. The
>   executor function is executed immediately by the Promise
>   implementation, passing resolve and reject functions (the executor is
>   called before the Promise constructor even returns the created
>   object).

So it should be only a **reference** to function, notice that when you call it with checkDimensions() the JS execute the function immediately.

So you will need it to be wrapped with a function reference, but the problem is the context of function has changed and the `checkDimensions()` is no longer exist inside the new context.

In order to keep the dimension variable context you can call the `checkDimensions` function from inside the `img.onload` with:

```
if (checkDimensions(img.width, img.height)) {
    return d.resolve();; 
}
else {
    return d.reject("Wrong dimensions");
}

this.initializeCheckImage(file)
    .then(() => console.log("RESOLVED"))
    .catch(() => console.log("REJECTED"));
```

**Edit:**

In order to keep the context of the wanted object you can use binding, with bind().

```
var readerOnload = function(e) {
    //code
}

reader.onload = readerOnload.bind(this);
```

Or with:

```
var self = this;

reader.onload = function() {
    //you can use self
}
```

In your case will have to do it once again for `imgOnload`.

Comment: I also came across the problem with the context. But it means, that inside the `img.onload`, I am also out of the context. So I have to move the function out of the object. It brings a few new problems, but thank you for pointing me the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest pass the value to resolve and receive on done.

```
  checkDimensions: function(dimensions) {
      console.log('entering chekDimensions');
      if (options.maxDimensionsWH > 0) {

        console.log(dimensions.width);
        console.log(dimensions.height);
        if ((dimensions.width <= options.maxDimensionsWH || dimensions.height <= options.maxDimensionsWH)
             && (dimensions.width > 0 && dimensions.height > 0)) {
            console.log('returning true');
            return true;    
        } else {
            console.log('returning false');
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        return true;
    }
  },
  initializeCheckImage: function(file) {
    console.log('entering initialization');
    var d = $.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        var img = new Image;
        img.onload = function() {
          this.checkWidth = img.width;
          this.checkHeight = img.height;
          console.log('initializing the image');
          console.log(this.checkWidth);
          console.log(this.checkHeight);
          d.resolve(
          {
             width:img.width,
             height:img.height
          });
        };
        console.log('assigning reader.result');
        img.src = reader.result;
      };
      console.log('assigning a file to the reader');
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      console.log('returning deferred');
      return d.promise();
  }
```

then

```
this.initializeCheckImage(file).done(function(dimensions) 
{ 
check = this.checkDimensions(dimensions) 
});
```